# A question based on application of Pigeonhole principle I am unable to think about

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

This is a question of an assignment I am trying to solve but unable to think how to use pigeonhole principle.

> Question is Let $S=\{1, 2, \ldots,n\}$ and let $r$ be an integer not belonging to $S$. Let $T=S \cup \{r\}$. Show that there exists an $x \in S$ such that sum of all elements $T\setminus\{x\}$  is divisible by $n$.

Can someone please tell how to solve this problem.

Comment: The usual trick here is to look at the consecutive sums $1, 1+2, 1+2+3, \cdots$ from $S$ and show that either $0\pmod n$ is hit or two of them coincide $\pmod n$.  Show that  you win either way.

Comment: Removing each of the $n$ elements $x$ of $S$ at a time, we get sums for the corresponding $T\setminus\{x\}$ that leave different remainders modulo $n$. Assume that none of them is $0$. Then there are $n$ different remainders of a sum and $n-1$ non-zero remainders.

Comment: @lulu That is the usual trick for a different problem. Here one needs not the sum of a segment, but the sum of all but one of the elements.

Comment: @lepidon  Absolutely correct.  Your method works, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-pigeonhole solution: The sum of the elements in $S$ is $n(n+1)/2+r.$ If $n$ is odd, just remove $r$ so that the sum is $n \cdot \frac{n+1}{2},$ which is divisible by $n.$

If $n=2m$ is even, then we require $0 \equiv m(2m+1) + r - x =  m+r - x \mod 2m,$ so just choose $x=m+r \mod 2m,$ or $x=2m$ if $m+r\equiv 0 \mod 2m.$

Edit: Check rtybase's comment.

Comment: You can't remove $r$, since $x\in S$ and $T\setminus \{x\}$. $r$ should always "stay". But you are not too far from the correct answer. I give you 10 minutes to correct your answer, otherwise I'll post mine ;)

Comment: @rtybase can you now post your answer?

Comment: Too late, it's in the comments. It will add nothing new.

Comment: By the way, if you want to fix your answer, apply [division with remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder): $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+r = qn+r_n$ where $0\leq r_n <n$. If $r_n \in \{1,...,n-1\}$ then $x=r_n$. If $r_n=0$ then $x=n$.  Since $\sum\limits_{k\in T\setminus \{x\}} k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}+r -x$ you're done.

Comment: I forgot to check back after posting. The problem is kind of dull and there's no point in rewriting rtybase's comment, so I'll just point to the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You go through element in $S$, removing it, calculating the sum and checking if it is divisible by $n$. You are guaranteed to find one because of the following reason -

First consider the sum $s_1$ of all the elements in $T \setminus \{1\}$. If we are lucky, $s_1 \equiv 0 \pmod n$. If not let $s_1 \equiv r \pmod n$ for some $1\leq r<n$.

Then consider $s_2$ which is the sum of all elements in $T \setminus \{2\}$.Make an observation that  $s_2 \equiv r+1 \pmod n$, since $s_2-s_1=1$.

So at each stage the difference in sums is $1$. So, after the first pick, we will certainly find such a sum since there $n-1$ numbers we can exhaust and we will definitely find a suitable number to remove in $n-r$ steps where $r \geq 1$.